# What is the event for upload in the mgt-file-list component

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using the react component of mgt-file-list an noticed there is no event for the upload option of the FileList in the documentation.

I tested and it seemed to upload a file in the UI but I never found the file in SharePoint.

Anyone knows what the deal is?

Is there an event signature I can use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present the file-list and underlying file upload don't expose any events for you to respond to around the file upload action.

Comment: That is very limited usage for programmers. Please enhance it! :-)